# font-size based on BOTH viewport width & height

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'll keep it short and straight forward, So I understand:

- VW changes the font-size based in the viewport width.
- VH changes the font-size based on the viewport height.

**My question is;**

Is there a way of scaling my font-size based on BOTH viewport width AND height?
So changing both the height and width of your browser would scale my font-size appropriately.

I ask because I would like to scale my text size appropriately to the container they are inside, my problem is that the container scales to 100% width and 100% height. So scaling the text size based on both the height and width would seem logical, unless there is a way to size based on the dimensions of its parent container?

---

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance

> I tried using percentages and looked at various font-sizing syntax yet i can't seem to find anything that scales based on both the width
>   and height, is there a reason for this?

Comment: See here for more on this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/. Font size is static, and based on either a static unit, or relative to a parent unit, and it doesn't change based on width or height of its container. In fact, fonts are quite strict in this way. But you can resize them based on vh or vw and this post shows how: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/. You can also mimic responsive font resizing with FitText.js: http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look of `vmin` and `vmax`.

- `1vmin` = `1vw` or `1vh`, whichever is smaller
- `1vmax` = `1vw` or `1vh`, whichever is larger

Comment: How did I not see this! Much appreciated.

Comment: Just be care about using `vmax` for IEs http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units @danjonescidtrix

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution for that, but it needs some calculations to be done.
I've had to fit a text to some predesigned space, and it's viewport size is, let's say, 300*200px. It can resize to fit another container.
Font size was selected as 18px.

So, in order to translate the font size to size relative to viewport:

```
[font size]*100/[viewport size]

18*100/300 = 6vw
18*100/200 = 9vh
```

Now just use half of each size:

```
font-size: calc(3vw+4.5vh);
```

That's it.